# How to implement autocompletetextview in Android Studio with an API call?

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, autocompletetextview

I am trying to use the autocompletetextview in Android Studio to provide suggestions for every letter keyed-in by the user.

Every time a letter is keyed-in, an API call is made like this,

```
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=app
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=appl
http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/v2/Lookup/json?input=apple
```

The JSON array that's returned from the API call is populated in the suggestions list-box.

So far I got the **activity_main.xml** file like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.raam.stockmarketviewer.MainActivity">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/stocks"
        android:hint="@string/hint" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

After this how should I structure the **MainActivity.java** file to accomplish the auto-suggestions feature?

Comment: just follow [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830) code snippet

Comment: and if you have no idea how to change the json part of the code i posted above,  [this](http://pastebin.com/VUm8P4mb) is a working solution for your case, just copy/paste it in your `Activity#onCreate` method

Comment: @pskink Thank you sooooo much for the working solution. Its working awesome. I just started learning Android Development a few days back and have to complete an App in a week for a school assignemnt. Sorry if I'm posting silly questions

Comment: @pskink Could you let me know how do we include the "Exchange" information also from the JSON array in the suggestions listbox?

Comment: the same way as "Name" was read

Comment: @pskink - I tried something like this - http://pastebin.com/CumY1iNB but the "Name" got replaced by "Exchange". What did I do wrong? :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109996/discussion-between-kemat-rochi-and-pskink).

Comment: becase you use the same textview in `int[] to` R.id.text2 is used twice

Comment: @pskink Then could you tell me how would be the right approach please?

Comment: if you want three different fields to be shown you should have a layout file with 3 TextViews, simple_list_item_2.xm layout file has only 2 such fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create a simple adapter and update it every time you get results

```
  List<String> suggestions = new ArrayList<>();
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter ;
   .
   .
   .
   // in your onCreate

   autocomplete = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.stocks);
   adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, suggestions);
   autocomplete.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

   autocomplete.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
          //retrieveData(s);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            retrieveData(s); //this will call your method every time the user stops typing, if you want to call it for each letter, call it in onTextChanged 

        }
    });
   .
   .
   .
   // where you get the data, I suppose in a list
   private void retrieveData(String s){
    //Do your stuff here with the String s and store the list of your results in the list suggestions
   suggestions = yourList;
   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

   }
```

Comment: A handler could also be used to trigger the retrieveData method here. It would help in maintaining the threshold. As shown here: https://www.truiton.com/2018/06/android-autocompletetextview-suggestions-from-webservice-call/

Comment: Sorry for digging this up again.. How are you referencing the adapter inside the retrieveData method? As that method is created outside of the onCreate method, do we pass the adapter in the method call?

Comment: The adapter is a global variable that I initialize in the onCreate, so that it can be used later by the retrieveData method

Comment: Please see another answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68313126/3904109