# How to make a search with autosuggest in the Bing Maps SDK?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bing-maps, bing-api

I am trying to use the Bing Maps SDK to display a map in which I show a `SearchView`. In this `SearchView` I want to search for locations and when I click on a suggested location, put a marker on the map at that location.

I have previously used the HERE SDK which has a documentation to do this but on Android I can't find any documentation about this Bing Maps SDK.

What I want to achieve is this in Android: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdk/mapcontrol/isdk/autosuggestui#TS

Answer (score 0):

Documentation on Bing Maps autosuggest service can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/autosuggest

You can use this with Androids [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView) to create a suggestion UI. You will retrieve the suggestions asynchronously from the above service. Here are a few good samples:

https://www.truiton.com/2018/06/android-autocompletetextview-suggestions-from-webservice-call/

[How to implement autocompletetextview in Android Studio with an API call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36799746/how-to-implement-autocompletetextview-in-android-studio-with-an-api-call)

This service does not return coordinates. This is done so that it isn't used as a replacement for the [geocoding service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/locations/find-a-location-by-query) and thus allows them to make this a lower cost service. When a suggestion is selected by the user, you will need to make a single call to a geocoder to get the coordinates of the `formattedAddress`, then you can use that to display a marker on the map. I recommend setting the result limit to 1 since you only want to top result.

In summary;

1. Use addTextChangedListener event of AutoCompleteTextView to retrieve suggestions from the autosuggest service.
2. Use setOnItemClickListener event of AutoCompleteTextView to retrieve the selection from the user, and pass the `formattedAddress` value into the geocoding service.
3. Use the coordinates from the geocoder response to create a marker and add to the map.